# Methods for improving/smoothing the load cell signal

Tags: filter, noise, load-cell

I am using a Delta AS02LC-A cell module and a Zemic 25 kg load cell. Here are some details of the load cell calibration certificate:

[image: Load cell calibration certificate]

And this is the appearance, specifications and wiring diagram of the cell module:

[image: Appearance, specifications and wiring diagram of the AS02LC-A cell module]

The load cell is connected in a 4-wire circuit as above. The SLD cable is also used.

With a set response/conversion time of 100 ms and no load, it gives continuously varying values in the range ±0.0006 kg or ±0.00024 mV. However, with a 10 ms response/conversion time set, the range changes to ±0.003 kg or ±0.0012 mV, i.e. the noise "increases" by a factor of 5.

Software filters are not used and are unacceptable as real time values are very important (at least 10 ms). How can the situation be improved if there is no direct access to the ADC?

Would it help to use an external 12 VDC power supply for the load cell instead of the 5 VDC provided by the cell module? Would reducing the wire length help? The calibration certificate warns that cutting the cable will affect the calibration of the full scale output.

I hope to achieve at least ±0.0001 kg or ±0.00004 mV for 100 ms response/conversion time, but dream of the same range for 10 ms. Is this possible given all the specifications?

What kind of electronic filters can be used and how can their parameters be calculated in this case? Any other ways to reduce this noise?

I have also encountered contradictory recommendations for twisted pair versus parallel lines for excitation, signal and sense cables. Which is correct? How about a ferrite core?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Typically you would run several software filters with differing time constants, and compare them. If the fast noisy one is within its noise band of the slow quiet one, you would report the slow, quiet signal. If the fast one is outside of its noise band, ie is showing that the real reading has probably changed, then you would switch to outputting the fast one, while resetting another slow quiet one to this new level, keeping the old slow one still running just in case it was a noise spike and not a real change.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are only 2 types of software filter available in the cell module (maximum/minimum and averaging). And both dramatically affect the response time, which is noticeable to the naked eye as it takes several seconds to get the current load value. There's not much I can do about that.

Comment: Is the averaging filter programmable for averaging time? In which case, run several with different averaging times. Or learn to write software.

Comment: Yes, it is. But, as I have already mentioned, it has an impact on the response time, which is unacceptable for real time load measurement, even with the shortest averaging time. Using this filter makes the situation worse by adding a more serious problem. What about electrical methods and noise reduction that have no noticeable effect on the measured value?

Comment: Generally, any filtering you can do with hardware, you can do more flexibly and more cleverly with software. if you implement a simple lag filter in both hardware and software, they will behave similarly. But if you want to do comparisons, logic, non-linear operations, reset averages, change time constants on the fly, software is just so much more flexible. And those operations will allow you to craft a filtering system to behave like you want it to behave, rather than just what an analogue filter presents to you.

Comment: This sounds very interesting, thank you. Could you please tell me where I can find more information about software filtering algorithms and which one is better for my case?

Comment: I can't think of any published data, or useful search terms, but I'll return if I can. I strongly recommend you get a spreadsheet of your data, and try filters of different types on it. The fastest responding lowpass filters are moving average, or box-car filters, they can also be implemented very efficiently recursively with two additions per sample, and are impossible to implement in conventional analogue filter hardware. Compare the response of a long one and a short one side by side. Then you will develop some intuition for what can be achieved.

Comment: The thing is, all I know is that the noise amplitude is ±0.00024 mV for a 100 ms response/conversion time setting and ±0.0012 mV for 10 ms. The look of the load vs time graph can be almost anything. It is also impossible to reliably predict the next value, as it can change dramatically. So I am at a loss as to how it is possible to separate out this noise from the useful signal.